# Failed to resolve: com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:1.0.23

Tags: android, github

I am not able to Import the Library jaydeepw/poly-picker(https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker) in my project having error as

> "Failed to resolve: com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:1.0.23"

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 26

buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sharaddadhich.multipleimages_camera"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories{

maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
maven { url 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' }
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:1.0.23'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this version is not available on jitpack.io (build failed). [This issue](https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker/issues/114) refers to the same problem.

You can still take `v1.0.22` which is available :

```
compile 'com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:v1.0.22'
```

or clone the project, build it & include the generated `aar` file in your project